# Анимация видео при прокрутке страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, анимация

Всем привет! Столкнулась с такой проблемой, как анимация видео. У меня есть видео по середине сайта (которое не видно при загрузке страницы), и я хотела бы, чтобы при скролле страницы, когда фокус попадает на видео, оно начинает играть. Пробовала сделать через метод `scrollTop >= 100`, он работает, но при адаптации размеры страницы меняются и мой код некорректно работает. Не хочется каждый раз, при уменьшении страницы прописывать другие параметры для `scrollTop`, так как таких видео много на странице. И поэтому хотела спросить у вас есть ли какие-либо инструменты или библиотеки, которые позволяют делать такие анимации сразу при фокусе на видео? То есть при скроллинге страницы, когда на фокус попадает видео он начинает играть, при этом не надо указывать никакие `scrollTop`, и какие-то другие методы, указывающие высоту страницы. Сайт делала на чистом коде, с использованием Bootstrap'а. Заранее спасибо)))))

Comment: вам нужно поставить функцию-обработчик событий на скролл, написать такую функцию, которой даёшь элемент страницы, а он определяет, есть ли элемент в видимой для пользователя части экрана

Comment: есть какой-то `appear.js`, нашел по запросу: `js элемент в области видимости`

Comment: есть `getBoundingClientRect`